# Firebase error when deploying cloud function: Cannot find module ...firebase-functions\lib\bin\firebase-functions.js'

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I'm facing this issue and I don't know how to resolve it. I'd like to deploy a Firebase hosting app which use cloud functions from Firebase.

so here is the logs

```
firebase deploy --only functions:helloWorld

=== Deploying to 'qdconstruction-frontend'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase default for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase default to determine what to deploy
'D\my-project\functions\node_modules\.bin\' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\theparentdirofmy-project\firebase-functions\lib\bin\firebase-functions.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1134:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:128:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v18.19.1
```

my function folder contains the default function in the index.js
I did npm install in this folder too.

```
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");


exports.helloWorld = onRequest((request, response) => {
  logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

So I tried to change my node version, I tried to start a new project with only functions (which works). I'm using `nvm manager` to manage node. No problem with other node usage before.
so I'm wondering if it's possible to set firebase hosting and cloud functions in the same project? I think it should be since the `firebase init` propose multiple services from Firebase..
It's a new project so I'm using last versions generally.
I also noticed that

D\my-project\functions\node_modules.bin' is not recognized ...
Error: Cannot find module 'D:\theparentdirofmy-project\

the path are not the same. Is it normal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jesus I found the problem. My parent folder has a '&' character which cause the problem.